# Does logging a string information fall under magic strings?

Tags: c#, magic-string

I would like to know a base thing.

```
_logger.LogInformation("Hi, Am I magic string?");
```

In the above line, does the string fall under magic string?

Any hardcoded validation/action against a response/return is considered a "magic string" to me. (Eg: `_config["EmailTo"]` should be `_config.EmailTo`, `if(list.contains("error"))` should be `if(list.contains(errorValue))`

Appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: No.. next question?

Comment: In computer programming, a magic string is an input that a programmer believes will never come externally and which activates otherwise hidden functionality.

Comment: @TheGeneral He meant the “magic” as in “magic numbers.”

Comment: A log entry would never be considered a magic string, it has no procedural importance and its only static nature is the text for the consumption of the developer

Comment: _Magic_ stuff is _magic_ because it’s not descriptive and haphazard. Such a string in question is descriptive, doesn’t affect the code flow, and doesn’t confuse your friends, ―not magic.

Comment: `int magicnumber = 42; // what was the question again?`

Comment: @TheGeneral Spoken like a dev that's never had to parse IIS logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic exists when the audience expects one thing but sees another.

If there is any system that reads the log file and tries to interpret it and then take some action this string has become a contract/magic because changing it will confuse that system.

A good rule of thumb is to never parse logs unless there are well defined and guarded standards for the log. Parsing strings is not one of them in my opinion and experience. Error numbers are much better/safer.